# Displaying rest data from api in Angular using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

My app is using a service to bring in some data fro a mock api url. I have written the service but I get a error:

**Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

My JSON structure is: as follows:

```
[
    "result", [
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and White",
    "u_address_floor": "1",
    "u_address_line_1": "15 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP26789 All Colour",
    "u_address_floor": "2",
    "u_address_line_1": "14 London Road",
    "u_address_post_code": "78900"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2678 Black and Yellow",
    "u_address_floor": "3",
    "u_address_line_1": "13 Champs Elyses",
    "u_address_post_code": "78987"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP7898 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "4",
    "u_address_line_1": "17 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "5",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "6",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "7",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  }
 ]
]
```

I have created example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azjsa6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try in your ngOnInit:

```
this.incidents = data.result;
```

forked [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwqyaj).

Comment: in your ngOnInit, also consider to import HttpClientModule in your app.module like i did in stackblitz demo, you'r welcome.

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct but you did a small mistake. Check out the following line.

```
    ngOnInit() {
            this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
              this.loading = true;
              this.incidents = data['result']; // <---- this line.
              this.loading = false;
              console.log('Result - ', data);
              console.log('data is recieved');
            })
          }
        }
```

And don't forget to import HttpClient (if you are using)..

**Import HttpModule** :

```
     import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

**:)**

Answer (score 1):

Add this in component file

```
*ngFor="let incident of incidents.result"
```

and import HttpModule

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```